# If $\int_{a}^{b} f^4(x) dx=0$, can we say that $f=0$

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[a,b]\longrightarrow{R}$ continuous, we know that $$\int_{a}^{b} f^4(x) dx=0$$ Can we say that $f=0$?

Now, I am pretty sure the answer to this question is no. For example, I know that in the function definite in $[0,2]$,

$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, &x \neq 0 \\ 1, &  x=0 \end{cases}$
it's area is  $\int_{0}^{2} f(x)dx=0$

And this gives me an idea on how there are functions which have an area of $0$ even when $f\neq0$

Comment: That example is not continuous.  If $f(x)$ is continuous, and $b-a>0$, then your assumption does imply that $f=0$.

Comment: If $f(c)\neq 0$ for some $c\in [a,b]$.  Then there is a neighborhood of $c$ in which $f$ is non-zero and over that neighborhood the integral is positive.  As the integral is non-negative everywhere else, the entire integral must then be positive.

Comment: By $f^4(x)$, do you mean $(f(x))^4$ or $f(f(f(f(x))))$? The answer is different depending on which one (with the first one being given by Jose Carlos Santos).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Obama would have said, “Yes, we can!”

Otherwise, there is some $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x)\neq0$. By continuity, there are numbers $\varepsilon,\delta>0$ such that $|f(y)|>\delta$ when $|y-x|<\varepsilon$. So $f^4(y)>\delta^4$ for those $y$'s and you can deduce from this that $\int_a^bf^4(t)\,dt>0$.

Answer (score 3):

Your example is not a counterexample because it is not continuous.

---

For continuous functions, you may be familiar with the theorem

> If $g:[a,b]\to [0,\infty)$ is a continuous function and $\int_a^b g(x)dx=0$, then $\forall x\in [a,b]: g(x)=0$

You can use this (fairly easy to prove) theorem (usually proven during an introductory calculus course) to show that $f^4(x)=0$ for all $x$, and then $f\equiv 0$ follows simply.